# Laravel Undefined Index on Model Constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my Model's constructor I have put together;

```
public function __construct($attributes = array())  {

    parent::__construct($attributes);

    var_dump($attributes);
    exit;
}
```

The var_dump output is;

`array(1) { ["table"]=> string(14) "participants_2" }`

But when I try this;

```
public function __construct($attributes = array())  {

    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->table = $attributes["table"];
}
```

I get;

```
ErrorException in Participant.php:
Undefined index: table
```

And it doesn't matter if I put the `$this` line before or after the `parent::__construct` line. How can this be an undefined index? I have defined it, right?

Maybe it is a Laravel problem?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is different contexts... Try var_dumping and setting in one go.

Comment: how did you solve?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. In my case the method was called without arguments the first time which caused error message and **with** arguments the second time. Check if that's not your case.

It that's it - you can add simple check to see if that element `isset()`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass some parameters to model constructor, you should do:

```
public function __construct($resource, array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->table= $resource;
    }
```

**Not do**

```
public function __construct($attributes = array())  {

    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->table = $attributes["table"];
}
```

because $attributes is for model instance data, not for parameters